# Methods/classes needed for file installer package

Tags: java, file, copy, paste, delete-file

I am looking for code snippets/methods/classes that will help me do several things (several different classes and methods are needed)

This is in java, and I would like to keep it in java

What needs to be done:

1. Create external folders (possible on another drive, under directories in the %appdata% folder)
2. Copy files, sending different file types and names to different folders
3. Detect if certain folders exist
4. Create new folders
5. Delete files inside of a .jar/delete files (either works)
6. Delete the contents of a folder

I am looking for the classes and methods I need to achieve these goals. It would also help to have some example method calls.

Comment: Oho, I do not think you searched very hard there my friend.

Comment: it is not the place where you get code for your requirements. What is your research effort involved in arriving the solution ?

Comment: I'm not asking for a full program. I'm asking about which tools I need to do these tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [java.io.File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) would satisfy most of those requirements. See also [Apache Commons FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) for a higher-level interface to the file system.

[java.util.jar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/package-summary.html) will satisfy your Jar file requirements.

Comment: As you are the only answer and you have provided enough information to help me get these functions done, you are now the accepted answer